# SpringFrameWork: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: android, json, spring, rest, parsing

I am working in an Android app that gets the data from the Server through REST services.

Now I have to make a POST on the REST service with a Body. But i am having problem doing that. I am using SPRINGFRAMEWORK to communicate with the REST service. But I am having this error:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error

Here is my code for posting:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error

```
final String url = "http://mywebsite.com/login";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);



HttpEntity<Credentials> entity = new HttpEntity<>(credentials ,requestHeaders);

//the object "CREDENTIALS" has the valus that should be sent as BODY in the REST Service
```

For posting i used two ways, but none of them worked:

```
ResponseEntity<AllData> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, AllData.class);
```

or

```
ResponseEntity<AllData> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, AllData.class );
```

Any idea why I am having this problem??

P.s. I checked many of the questions that were like me but in none of them I could find a answer. I am trying since some days but can't figure out what the problem is :@

Comment: As the error suggests, it is 500 Internal Server Error. So we need the server code to check what is wrong with it

Comment: I tried the REST service with POSTMAN (the Google ExtensioN) and also some other Online REST service testing tools, and it worked perfectly. But here it isn't working :(

Comment: can you paste the json body that you used to send the request and also your AllData class

Comment: You would have to put the Server side code.

Answer (score 1):

I was exactly the same problem, and I managed to solve it. Bringing to your example I needed to change the Credentials entity type to the same ResponseEntity type. Would be like this :

```
final String url = "http://mywebsite.com/login";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


AllData allData = new AllData();

HttpEntity<AllData> entity = new HttpEntity<>(allData, requestHeaders);

ResponseEntity<AllData> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, AllData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it's working from postman and other I'm guessing it's an encoding or headers issue.
I guess the easiest way to find the problem will be to use a proxy like fiddler and check the compare the headers and data sent from the Android device to those sent by postman or another tool